# Export Mysql with gzip commands to properly create a compressed file & import in AWS

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

Export with gzip commands to properly create a compressed file of a MySQL database & import to AWS RDS Server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Export From RDS Server:

```
mysqldump -h mywebinstance.rds.amazonaws.com -u myuser -p my-db-name | gzip > /var/www/html/dev-16-6-2022.sql.gz
```

Import to RDS Server:

```
gunzip < /var/www/html/dev-16-6-2022.sql.gz | mysql -h mywebinstance.rds.amazonaws.com -u myuser -p my-db-name
```